# TTStyledTextLabel inside UITextView

Tags: iphone, scroll, uitextview, ttstyledtextlabel

I have a need to display text that includes HTML tags etc and TTStyledTextLabel fits the bill.....but it does not scroll.

I placed one inside a UITextView but this refuses to scroll? If I enter the text directly in the UITextView it scrolls OK but then I see all the HTML unformatted.

Is there a way to set TTStyledTextLabel to scroll?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting the `TTStyledTextLabel` in a `UIScrollView`.

Alternately, you can consider using a `UIWebView` directly.

Comment: Bu this would require needing to know the size of the TTSyledTextLabel for use with content size.  ?

Comment: Perhaps. But see my addition above. If you just have HTML, you can load an HTML file in your bundle from a WebView. This allows scrolling and you do not need to know the size a priori.

Comment: lol I went for the webview before reading you next comment and yes this is probably the way to go ;-)  marked you up as you were right ;-) thanks

Answer (score 0):

I finally got a suitable work around...

CGSize constraintSize;

CGSize stringSize;

// make an overly big size allowance

constraintSize.width = 300;

constraintSize.height = 2000;

NSString *s = @"this can be text as long or as short as required...;

UIFont *f = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:14];

stringSize =[s sizeWithFont:f constrainedToSize: constraintSize lineBreakMode: UILineBreakModeWordWrap];

// create a label to accomodate the text

UILabel *l = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(14, 2, stringSize.width, stringSize.height)];

l.text = s;

[l setNumberOfLines:0];

[l sizeToFit];

// now create a TTStyledTextLabel to match the size we just obtained above

TTStyledTextLabel *tl = [[TTStyledTextLabel alloc] initWithFrame:[l frame]];

// set the text making use of links etc

tl.text = [TTStyledText textFromXHTML:l.text lineBreaks:YES URLs:YES];

[tl setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];

tl.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

UIScrollView *sv = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 185, 320, 300)];

// adjust scrollview content size to accomodate the TTStyledTextLabel

[sv setContentSize:CGSizeMake(tl.frame.size.width, tl.frame.size.height)];

[sv addSubview:tl];

[self.view addSubview:sv];

Now I can have an auto sizing TTStyledTextLabel that scrolls ;-)